# VB.NET System Info, How can I get the publish location or publishing folder location?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net

I know that

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

can get the installation folder.

But how can I get the location of publishing folder that I put in "PUBLISH" tab of my project? say.. (of course this will not work)

```
Application.PublishingPath
```

Thanks advance for the replies.. =)

P.S. I only want to know the folder path of publishing folder through a msgbox.

Comment: More information is required.  Give an example of the "Publishing" path your trying to determine.

Comment: I think you better ask the question on StackOverflow as it is oriented towards developers.